# VBA Open File From Hyperlink

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

With some help along the way, I'm using the code below to perform the following:

- Extract files from a given path,
- inserting the filename into column **C**,
- The filepath into column **D**, and
- A hyperlink on each row in column **B**, which the user selects taking them to to the **'Save As Dialog'** allowing the user to save the file.

  ```
  Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

  Dim fName As String
  Dim Lastrow As Long

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
  ' display file properties
      Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = FileItem.Name
      Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
      iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number
  ''''''''
  '' As the progress bar is set for 0 to 100, treat
  '' the progress as a percentage when calculating
  ''''''''
      frm.prgStatus.Value = (xCur / xMax) * 100
  '' Add 1 to xCur ready for next file
      xCur = xCur + 1
      Next FileItem

      Range("C10").CurrentRegion.Select
      Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C10"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
      DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

      With ActiveSheet
          Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
          Lastrow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
      End With

      If IncludeSubfolders Then
          For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
              ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
              Next SubFolder
          End If
          Set FileItem = Nothing
          Set SourceFolder = Nothing
          Set FSO = Nothing

          For iRow = 10 To Lastrow
              Cells(iRow, 2).Formula = iRow - 9
              Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Path
              ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Cells(iRow, 2), Address:="", _
              ScreenTip:=CStr(iRow - 9)
          Next
      End Sub
  ```

When the user clicks on the hyperlink, this is the 'Follow Hyperlink' code which runs allowing the user to save the file.

*****UPDATED CODE*****

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Dim FSO
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sDFolder As String
    Dim thiswb As Workbook ', wb As Workbook

    On Error GoTo CleanExit:

'Disable events so the user doesn't see the codes selection
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'Define workbooks so we don't lose scope while selecting sFile(thisworkbook = workbook were the code is located).
    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook
'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' This line was commented out because we no longer need to cope with 2 excel workbooks open at the same time.
'Target.Range.Value is the selection of the Hyperlink Path. Due to the address of the Hyperlink being "" we just assign the value to a
'temporary variable which is not used so the Click on event is still triggers
    temp = Target.Range.Value
'Activate the wb, and attribute the File.Path located 1 column left of the Hyperlink/ActiveCell
    thiswb.Activate
    sFile = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 2).Value

    If UCase$(Mid$(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".") + 1)) = "DOCX" Then

    Application.EnableEvents = True
        Select Case MsgBox("Do you wish to view the file before saving?", vbYesNoCancel Or vbQuestion, "Save or View?")
            Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
            Case vbYes:
                With CreateObject("Word.Application")
                    .Visible = True
                    .Documents.Open sFile
                    .Activate
                End With
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End If

'Declare a variable as a FileDialog Object
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
'Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
'Allow only single selection on Folders
    fldr.AllowMultiSelect = False
'Show Folder picker dialog box to user and wait for user action
    fldr.Show

'Did the user cancel?
    If fldr.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
'Add the end slash of the path selected in the dialog box for the copy operation
        sDFolder = fldr.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
'FSO System object to copy the file
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' Copy File from (source = sFile), destination , (Overwrite True = replace file with the same name)
        FSO.CopyFile (sFile), sDFolder, True
        MsgBox "File Saved!"
    Else
'Do anything you need to do if you didn't get a filename.
    MsgBox "You choose not to save the file!"

    End If
' Check if there's multiple excel workbooks open and close workbook that is not needed
' section commented out because the Hyperlinks no longer Open the selected file
' If Not thiswb.Name = wb.Name Then
'     wb.Close
' End If
CleanExit:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The code works fine, but I'm looking to change this a little, and what I've tried so far hasn't worked.

What I'd like to do is change this by extracting the file extension, from the path in column **D**, and if the extension is .docx, I would like the user to be able to view the file rather than being taken straight to the 'Save As Dialog'.

I'm a little out of my depth and as I say the changes I've made have not worked.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly have a look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may go about achieving this.

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: Why don't you write code to just save each file with the filename you want rather than getting someone to do it manually?

Comment: HI @TobyAllen, thank you very for taking the time to reply to my post. The  idea behind allowing the user to save the file manually is so they can browse the folder the wish to say on their local computer. Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the extension, ask, pass the file to Word:

```
sFile = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column + 2).Value

If UCase$(Mid$(sFile, InStrRev(sFile, ".") + 1)) = "DOCX" Then
    Select Case MsgBox("View before saving?", vbYesNoCancel Or vbQuestion, "Save or View?")
        Case vbCancel: Exit Sub
        Case vbYes:
            With CreateObject("Word.Application")
                .Visible = True
                .Documents.Open sFile
                .Activate
            End With
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End If
```

Comment: Hi @Alex K. thank for taking the time to reply to my post and for putting the code together. Forgive me, but could you tell me please where I would incorporate this into my existing code.  Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: The first line above is from your code so under your `sFile = ...`

Comment: Hi Alex K. this works perfectly thank you so very much for your help, I really appreciate it. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Hi @Alex K. I'm sorry to trouble you with this agian, but I've been continuing my testing with the code you kindly provided and I've come up against a problem. If the user selects a '.docx' file and views this, the process works fine, but then if the user then tries to select any other hyperlink in the list whether they are '.docx' file types or not, the hyperlinks are deactivated. Have you any idea how I may overcome this please. Kind Regards and Many thanks. Chris

Comment: Ensure you Application.EnableEvents = True before exiting or remove the Application.EnableEvents calls entirely

Comment: Hi @Alex K., thank you for this. I've updated my code as per the update in my original post and this works great. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris